# AngularJS controller only working on first view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some problems running my first AngularJS app. When I run my app all objects on my index are displayed properly. When I click on my hyperlink to move to view-2 all objects are displayed on HTML like plain text {{object.property}} What am I doing wrong?

This is my index.html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tutorialApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Tutorial App</title>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MyController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
</DOCTYPE>
```

this is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('tutorialApp', ["ngRoute", "MyControllerModule"])

    app.config(function ($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider

            .when("/", {
                controller: "MyController",
                templateUrl: "views/one.html"
            })


            .when("/two", {
                controller: "ControllerTwo",
                templateUrl: "views/two.html"
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });
    });
```

this is my MyController.js:

```
angular.module("MyControllerModule", [])

.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope){

$scope.myFirstObject = {};
$scope.myFirstObject.title = "Main Page";
$scope.myFirstObject.subTitle = "Sub Title";

$scope.myFirstObject.bindOutput = 13;

$scope.myFirstObject.firstname = "Wheelchair";
$scope.myFirstObject.lastname = "Terminator";

$scope.timesTwo = function(){
    $scope.myFirstObject.bindOutput *= 2;
}

}])

.directive("myFirstDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div>Hello how are you?</div>"
    }
})

.controller("ControllerTwo", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.testObject = {};
    $scope.testObject.doSomething = "TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST!";

}
]);
```

This is my /views/one.html:

```
<h1>{{myFirstObject.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{myFirstObject.subTitle}}</h2>

<p>Number: {{2 + 2}}</p>
<p>String: {{myFirstObject.firstname + " " + myFirstObject.lastname}}</p>
<p><b>Multiply a number by two: {{myFirstObject.bindOutput | currency}}</b></p>

<button ng-click="timesTwo()">CLICK TO MULTIPLY</button><br>

<br>
<label>First Name:</label>
<input ng-model="myFirstObject.firstname">
<br>
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input ng-model="myFirstObject.lastname">
<br>
<a href="views/two.html">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<my-first-directive></my-first-directive>
```

this is my /views/two.html

```
<h1>Second View</h1>
<h2>this is the second view...</h2>
<br>
<br>

<p>Call object string: {{testObject.doSomething}}</p>
```

Comment: press `f12` and `open console`, you have some error, and paste that error in the question.

Comment: it's not showing anything in the console when i swap from one.html to two.html (firefox debugger)

Comment: open console and refresh the page, you will get to see the errors

Comment: please change <a href="views/two.html">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a> to <a href="/two">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a> in your one.html

Comment: @PawanGupta When i do it like that and click hyperlink in one.html it takes me to a empty white page and url in browser becomes localhost:8080/two

Answer (score 0):

Change the `href` to route. Not html page.

`<a href="views/two.html">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a>`

This should be

`<a href="#/two">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a>`

As you did in the question, that calls the new html page to load into the browser. Not template of angular app. So, all the unknown stuff like `{{object.property}}` happens.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and when i click on hyperlink now nothing happens stays on same page but the browser url changes to: http://localhost:8080/#!/#%2Ftwo

Comment: Try this:  `href="#!/two"`

Comment: YES IT WORKED! Wow thanks a million.. finally can go on with my tutorial :D

Comment: Glad it helped you. If it really helps you, accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

**`<a href="#two">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a>`**

Observe, `href="#two"`

```
<h1>{{myFirstObject.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{myFirstObject.subTitle}}</h2>

<p>Number: {{2 + 2}}</p>
<p>String: {{myFirstObject.firstname + " " + myFirstObject.lastname}}</p>
<p><b>Multiply a number by two: {{myFirstObject.bindOutput | currency}}</b></p>

<button ng-click="timesTwo()">CLICK TO MULTIPLY</button><br>

<br>
<label>First Name:</label>
<input ng-model="myFirstObject.firstname">
<br>
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input ng-model="myFirstObject.lastname">
<br>
<a href="#two">CLICK HERE FOR SECOND VIEW</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<my-first-directive></my-first-directive>
```

[Check this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing)

**EDIT:**

You seems to have issue with `#` url's

Solution:

## HTML5 Mode

Configuration:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/two', {
    templateUrl: 'views/two.html',
  });
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(true);
```

You should set the base in HTML-file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

In this mode you can use links without the # in HTML files

```
<a href="/two">link</a>
```

example:

```
http://test.com/base/two
```